# Android 6.0.1 - Permission issue = wifiManager.getScanResults() returns 0

Tags: android, android-permissions, wifimanager

The permissionsList.add() doesn't work but MainActivity.this.requestPermissions() works fine. The issue is that it brings a dialog box asking if the user allow the location permission.

Why adding the permission does not work?

Is there a way to avoid the dialog box?

See my minimal code below:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
WifiManager wifiManager;
WifiBroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver;

Context context;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    context = getApplicationContext();

    List<String> permissionsList = new ArrayList<String>();
    permissionsList.add(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
    permissionsList.add(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if(checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            MainActivity.this.requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 100);
            MainActivity.this.requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 100);
            }
        }

        Button scan = (Button) findViewById(R.id.scan);

        wifiManager = (WifiManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);

        scan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
               if(wifiManager != null)
                    wifiManager.startScan();
            }
        });


        broadcastReceiver = new WifiBroadcastReceiver();

        // On attache le receiver au scan result
        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(
                WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));

    }

    public class WifiBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        private WifiManager wifiManager;


        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            wifiManager = ((MainActivity) context).getCurrentWifiManager();
            List<ScanResult> listeScan = wifiManager.getScanResults();
          }
    }


    public WifiManager getCurrentWifiManager() {
        return wifiManager;
    }

 }
```

And here is the manifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.bernard_zelmans.checksecurity">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Ping"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Beginning in Android 6.0 (API level 23), users grant permissions to
>   apps while the app is running, not when they install the app. This
>   approach streamlines the app install process, since the user does not
>   need to grant permissions when they install or update the app. It also
>   gives the user more control over the app's functionality; for example,
>   a user could choose to give a camera app access to the camera but not
>   to the device location. The user can revoke the permissions at any
>   time, by going to the app's Settings screen.

Resource and more to read:

- https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html
- https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#normal-dangerous

Comment: This is understood. This is the reason I am adding the permissions at the beginning of the code. That did not work. Only the request permission works. The drawback is the dialog box asking the user to allow/deny the permissions.

Comment: As far as I know there is no work around regarding the dialog box.

Comment: RE-reading your point, the is only the choice of requesting and not adding. Why is there an add method? It looks to me that when I install an app using a camera it asks me at the install process? Is location special? I'il RE-read the doc.

Comment: This might enlighten you https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#normal-dangerous

Comment: Hum... Not easy. IC I née

Comment: Sorry for the typo. If I need CAMERA MICROPHONE LOCATION, I must  require permission for the 3 of them?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126146/discussion-between-narb-and-maytham-mahtyam).